# django-celery: No result backend configured

Tags: django, django-celery

I am trying to use django-celery in my project

In settings.py I have

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
```

The server started fine with

```
python manage.py celeryd --setting=settings
```

But if I want to access a result from a delayed task, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\result.py", line 108, in ready
    return self.status in self.backend.READY_STATES
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\result.py", line 196, in status
    return self.state
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\result.py", line 191, in state
    return self.backend.get_status(self.task_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\base.py", line 404, in _is
_disabled
    raise NotImplementedError("No result backend configured.  "
NotImplementedError: No result backend configured.  Please see the documentation
 for more information.
```

It is very strange because when I just run celeryd (with the same celery settings), it works just fine. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem while getting the result back from the celery task although the celery task was executed ( console logs). What i found was, i had the same setting `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"` in django settings.py but i had also instantiated celery in the tasks.py

`celery = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost')` - which i suppose overrides the settings.py property and hence it was not configuring the backend server for my celery instance which is used to store the results.

i removed this and let django get celery get properties from settings.py and the sample code worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just running the samples from http://www.celeryproject.org/tutorials/first-steps-with-celery/, you need to run the console via manage.py:

% python manage.py shell

Answer (score 2):

For those who are in a desperate search for a solution like I was.

Put this line at the end of the `settings.py` script:

```
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

Looks like **django-celery** is not going to consider it's own settings without a strict order.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that I was passing the CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND argument to the celery constructor:

```
Celery('proj',
         broker = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',
         CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='amqp://',
         include=['proj.tasks'])
```

The solution was to use the backend argument instead:

```
Celery('proj',
         broker = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',
         backend='amqp://',
         include=['proj.tasks'])
```

Answer (score 1):

For users encountering this issue in 2023. If you are using Celery version 5.0 or greater, set CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "rpc://" in settings. If you are initializing the celery app, use the below code:

```
Celery('your_project_name',
     broker = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//',
     backend='rpc://',
     include=['proj.tasks'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some how the console has to have django environment set up in order to pick up the settings. For example, in PyCharm you can run django console, in which everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

See [AMQP BACKEND SETTINGS](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#amqp-backend-settings) for better understanding

> Note The AMQP backend requires RabbitMQ 1.1.0 or higher to
> automatically expire results. If you are running an older version of
> RabbitMQ you should disable result expiration like this:
> `CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = None`

Try adding the below line to your settings.py:

`CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 18000 # 5 hours`